# Issues with dropdown nav-bar

Tags: javascript, css

Pls av been trying to put up a dropdown bar on my page but is not working beside I linked my jQuery.min.js file and my bootstrap.css file but is not yet working can someone pls help me

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask] and provide [mcve] of your code and explain what is the problem you are facing.

Comment: There's no linked file.

Comment: what version of bootstrap? do you use angular or something?

Comment: please add your code that only way we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Check the below snippet for `dropdown` Also note when you use bootstrap you have to link follow files

- **bootstrap.min.css**
- **jquery.min.js**
- **bootstrap.min.js**

only then it will work

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```